# Create a Node with Fields and turn them into tabs in a display?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I am a Drupal 7 newbie, I am only proficient in CSS and HTML and I am looking for someone to point me in the right direction(to documentation/modules/advice) on how to execute what I am trying to do or even telling me if it is possible or not.

I tried making tabs already, I was using quick tabs and multiple blocks but I found that would be inefficient because I need 12 pages with tabs and each has at least 2-3 tabs with content each that need to be eventually edited by heads of departments.

**What I am trying to do:**

- Create a page with multiple tabs and content inside of it.
- When editing the node there should be multiple tabs at the top corresponding with the tabs on the page and an option to add more tabs up to a limit
- Tabs should have a title and body field.

Some examples of the content of the tabs: welcome, about, programme. They would just have 1 or two paragraphs of content.

**How I was thinking it could be done:**

- Creating a New Field type called Tab, that groups a title & body
- Creating a New Structure type that has max of 6 Tabs
- Create a new display to have the fields organized into tabs.
- Download Module for displaying tabs in editing mode?

I just don't know how to make that possible or if it is. Can someone point me in the right direction or help me to come up with a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach to create tabs to nest your content for visitors to see on your pages without much hassle is to try to use the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module in D7.

Another solution is to use the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module with 2 fields: title and body. And try to setup Field Groups possibly to treat each paragraph entry as a Tab on the page ...